# Installing to a hdd with known bad sectors

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I am planning to wipe an existing system and put Ubuntu on it. During the preparation I discovered there are bad sectors on it (using chkdsk on Windows). Will this prevent regular Ubuntu installer from working? If so, I probably need to slip in a manual `fsck` some time during the installation?

PS: This is an old system so it is either getting it to work (in some way) or scrapping it.

Comment: It should work. A few bad sectors will be reallocated automatically, so as long as the HDD hasn't failed, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem unless the HDD is in its death throes. As @mikewhatever said, bad sectors are remapped automatically by the hard drive as it is completely normal and somewhat expected for one or two sectors to go bad eventually.

I have installed Lubuntu on a system that showed 1 bad sector. The installer didn't complain about anything and I didn't notice anything particularly off.